# Ubuntu terminal not showing current folder

Tags: shell-script, terminal

So I have a script to open new terminal windows with 2 tabs, but when I run it, current directory in these tabs is not displayed. When using default ubuntu's bashrc it works fine, but changing `\w` to `\W` results in current folder not showing until using `cd`, after that it works ok. What's the problem here?

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab  --working-directory="/mnt/0000000000/Users/Admin/Desktop/folder1/" --tab  --working-directory="/mnt/0000000000/Users/Admin/Desktop/folder2/"
exit 0
```

PS1s are:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
```

and

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u: \W\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Changing `/Desktop/folder1/` to `/Desktop/folder1` solves things. For some reason `\W` is sensitive to that last slash, while `\w` is not, yet path like `"~/"` woks fine in both cases.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the script. What do you mean by `\w` and `\W`? In what directory are you when running the script? Normally the `PS1` variable controls what's shown before the cursor, but since a `cd` fixes your problem, I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: I'm in the home directory. There are 3 PS1 instances in ubuntu's bashrc. If I leave `\w` (to display full path) in them, it shows full path in new window right away, but if I change it to `\W` (to display only last part of path) directory name will be missing till I go somewhere.

Comment: please update with your PS1.  I am unable to duplicate this behavior with my PS1, which is set to `[\u@\h]-[$(date +'%a %b %e %H:%M %p')]:[\w] bash-[\!]\$ `. If I change it to `[\u@\h]-[$(date +'%a %b %e %H:%M %p')]:[\W] bash-[\!]\$ ` it still works as expected.

Comment: Made it work. I used "/folder1/folder2/" as my path1 and 2, and removing last `/` fixed it. Can you explain why this caused a problem and why "~/" in the script works even with slash there?

Comment: @tyrande, please, [edit] your question to add any new information or other changes. It's hard to follow what the question is, if half of it is in the comments. Also, post that `PS1`.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason `\W` is sensitive to that last slash, […]

That reason is documented in the user manual for your shell program:

> `\W`     the basename of the current working directory […]

The basename as far as your shell is concerned is the portion following the final slash.  The basename of `/Desktop/folder1` is thus `folder1`, whereas the basename of `/Desktop/folder1/` is the zero-length string that follows that final slash.

This is not quite the POSIX definition of a basename, and not what the `basename` command will tell you; but it is an approximation commonly used in Unix and Linux programs.